# Flagging the top X rows using multiple criteria across multiple geographies (ranking with multiple criteria in excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ranking

I want to be able to Rank the top X accounts by geography (assuming Geographies are letters). The number of accounts will be a manual input which I already have in a table looking like this:

[image]

My two criteria for ranking are: First prioritize ranking when column "Special?" = Y, and then go through ascending order of $ for remainder of the count.

To rank there would be an additional column that says "Y" if it falls within the top X accounts for that geo (you can see it below but its cutoff on purpose)

[image]

The total of "Y" in the next column should equal my preferred number of ranking. For example I should see 2 A with "Y", 1 B with "Y", etc... and prioritize first "Special?" then the highest "$".

Of course this is a small sample data size but I am hoping to do this with dozens of geographies and thousands of rows.

Here is what the answer would look like in the example -- I am trying to replicate via formula.

[image]

I have just been doing it manually.

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables for posting your sample data in your question. Also good to know: where is that Rank the top-table?

Answer (score 0):

I think, instead of listing `Y` in column D for the condition being met you'd be more interested in the rank order. If you have `A` listed twice,  marking it `Y` does not say anything about the rank place. Only that it is in the top n.

This formula spills the result in order of your top rank table in correct order of ranking:

```
=LET( top, E2:F5,
     data, A2:C25,
 priority, SORT(
                HSTACK( CHOOSECOLS(data,1,2),
                        INDEX(data,,2)+((INDEX(data,,3)="Y")*9^9)),
                3,
                -1),
DROP( REDUCE( 0, SEQUENCE(ROWS(top)),
      LAMBDA( x, y,
      VSTACK( x,
              TAKE(
                   FILTER(TAKE(priority,,2),
                          INDEX(priority,,1)=INDEX(top,y,1)),
                   INDEX(top,y,2))))),1))
```

Another benefit of this approach is it dealing with duplicate Geo's with same `$`. For instance if you'd want to list the top 2 of `B`, you'd have `$` `12` listed first, because that's marked special, but for second ranking you'd have `$` `99` twice.
This formula will list only one of these and 2 of these along the special-marked string if you'd want the top 3 listed.

The uses the first 2 columns and appends an array to the right where all `special` marked `$`'s will get a large number (9^9) added, so they're always higher than non-special `$`'s. This array is used to sort the previous columns appended to it.
Than REDUCE will make it possible to stack the filter results of the top n `$`'s for each individual geo.

[image]